# Dates not working on the X axis

Tags: r

I have daily `time series` data from 1970 to 2010 and I am trying to make a `lineplot` where the colour of the line changes depending on the value of the y axis.

I found this really nice example using [plotrix](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/200-change-color-in-lineplot-following-y-value/#200) and it works great but when I use my data the date appears on the `X axis` as numbers rather than `Dates`, even though the data is in Date format. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I have plotted the data in `ggplot` before with no problems and the dates appear as dates.

Here is my code with some test data (these dates are showing up as numbers too):

```
#Test data
test_date <- seq.Date(as.Date("1970-01-01"), as.Date("2010-01-31"), by = "day")
numbers <- seq(1:length(test_date))

library(plotrix)
#Plot
par(mar=c(4, 4, 2, 2))
clplot(test_date, numbers, main = "", lwd = 3, levels = c(1000, 5000, 10000), cols= c("black", "Blue", "Cyan", "Green"), showcuts = T, bty = "n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the dates to decimal using lubridate:

```
library(lubridate)
library(plotrix)

clplot(decimal_date(test_date), numbers, main = "", lwd = 3, 
   levels = c(1000, 5000, 10000), cols= c("black", "Blue", "Cyan", "Green"),
   showcuts = TRUE, bty = "n", xlab = "")
```

[image: screenshot]